# `make` without manual Makefile writing

Tags: c, makefile

I'll have two write a project or two in plain C this year. To automate the compilation (besides, I'd like to use the build plugin for Atom) I'd like to have a Makefile.

But I'm not really fond of specifying all the commands manually. I'd rather specify the source files and headers (in the correct order) and let the program build the rest for me.

Is there any tool that I could use? Or should I reconsider writing the Makefiles manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`make` have many *implicit rules* that will create object files from C source file without you writing any commands. All you really need to do is list the object files needed for the program.

For example, lets say you have to source files, `a.c` and `b.c`, and you want to create the program `p`., then all you need is

```
p : a.o b.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

`$(CC)` is the variable used for the C compiler frontend program, which is also used to link. `make` creates this for you and it's usually `cc`.

`$^` is a list of all per-requisites for the rule, in this case `a.o b.o`.

`$@` is the name of the target of the rule, in this case `p`.

Using this very simple makefile, `make` will compile the C sources to object files, and then with the provided rule link the object files into an executable program.

---

From the above makefile you can start customizing, for example tell `make` to explicitly use `gcc` instead of `cc` by setting the `CC` variable. Or set special compiler flags by creating and setting the `CFLAGS` variable. Adding targets to "clean" (usually remove the program and the object files). And much much more.

I suggest you learn about `make` and makefiles, and for this you should read [the GNU make online manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/), before going on to other build systems.

The [GNU build system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system) is still very common, but it have been losing ground lately, mostly to [CMake](http://cmake.org/) (which I personally favor) but there are many other build systems out there. Some (like CMake) can be used to generate makefiles, while others are straight replacements for `make`.

Answer (score 2):

This should be seen as an addition to Joachims answer on how to string it all together.

I have a makefile that I use for more or less everything, that has automatic dependency discovery and automatic source file discovery.
While is might not be the right fit for large projects, I find it extremly convinient for small prototypes and programs.

I have collected and commented the importent parts here:

```
CC:=gcc                 # Define the Compiler
CFLAGS:=-O2 -g          # Define the Compiler Options
SRC_DIR:=src            # Source is in this folder
BIN_DIR:=bin            # objects will be places in this folder

# Discover all C files
SRC:=$(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -type f -name *.c)
# Every C file is compiled into one object file
OBJ:=$(addprefix bin/,$(notdir $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(C_SRC))))
# Every C file creates a dependency file
DEP:=$(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(C_SRC)

# Include the dependencies
-include $(DEP)

all: executable

# Bind all objects into the executable
executable: $(OBJ)
        $(CC) $^ -o executable

# Recipe to create the dependencie files from the source files
.d: %.c
        $(CC) -MM -MT"$(BIN_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.c=.o))" -MF "$@" "$<"

# Recipe to do the compilation
$(C_OBJ):bin/%.o:
        -$(STYLEC) $^
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

This will take all source files from the src/ folder, generate the dependencies with the gcc and then do the correct compilation/binding.

Comment: I guess your missing `BIN_DIR` in the `OBJ :=` line. You hardcoded `bin`. Besides, what are the dependencies? I never came across them. And what is `$<`?

Comment: The dependencies are generated by the GCC via -MM. They are generated by inspecting the include instructions in the C sources. 
For every .c file, a fitting .d file will be created by the GCC and since we have found all source files, we know what dependency files we can expect and include.

Comment: The $< make variable contains the first prerequisite of a recipe, this is the c file that is creating the object. Further information about the automatic variables can be found here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html


And thanks for the reminder about the hardcoded bin.

Comment: Yes, but what are the dependency files for?

Comment: I personally find it extremely tedious to specify the dependencies myself. If I have a c file test.c that includes header files a.h, b.h and c.h, the manual way to express this relation in a Makefile would be 'test.o: test.c a.h b.h c.h'. This would have to be updated whenever you include a new header or new c file. This Makefile automates this process for you, you only need to specify which objects should be linked together in the binary.

Comment: Some further research guided me to an alternative generation of `SRC` and `OBJ`: `SRC := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)` 
`OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)`. Are there any advantages of one above another?

Comment: Besides, what will happen to with your Makefile if `$(BIN_DIR)` doesn't exist? I guess the build will fail.

Comment: Yes, the build will fail when bindir doesn't exist. The difference in the source file discovery is that my solution is able to find all source files in the SRC_DIR and all it's containing directories while the wildcard solution is only able to find the sources in the given directory. If you don't plan on having a director tree in src, I'd go with the wildcard solution. I want my objects file not mirror the directory structure of the src folder, so i went with this solution. It doesn't really matter to much.